# PHP não pega os valores de preenchimento automático

Tags: php, post, input

Bom dia,

Estou com um pequeno problema e espero que vocês possam me ajudar:

**Busca_CEP**

```
<!-- Adicionando JQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function limpa_formulário_cep() {
            // Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
            $("#rua").val("");
            $("#bairro").val("");
            $("#cidade").val("");
            $("#uf").val("");
            $("#ibge").val("");
        }

        //Quando o campo cep perde o foco.
        $("#cep").blur(function() {

            //Nova variável com valor do campo "cep".
            var cep = $(this).val();

            //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
            if (cep != "") {

                //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
                var validacep = /^[0-9]{5}-?[0-9]{3}$/;

                //Valida o formato do CEP.
                if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                    //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                    $("#rua").val("...")
                    $("#bairro").val("...")
                    $("#cidade").val("...")
                    $("#uf").val("...")
                    $("#ibge").val("...")

                    //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
                    $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                        if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                            //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                            $("#rua").val(dados.logradouro);
                            $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                            $("#cidade").val(dados.localidade);
                            $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                            $("#ibge").val(dados.ibge);
                        } //end if.
                        else {
                            //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                            limpa_formulário_cep();
                            alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                        }
                    });
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cep é inválido.
                    limpa_formulário_cep();
                    alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
                }
            } //end if.
            else {
                //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
                limpa_formulário_cep();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cep:
    <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9" /></label><br />
    <label>Rua:
    <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Cidade:
    <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
    <label>IBGE:
    <input name="ibge" type="text" id="ibge" size="8" /></label><br />
  </form>
</body>
```

Estou utilizando esse código disponibilizado pelo site http://viacep.com.br/exemplo/jquery/,
ele está funcionando perfeitamente, porém quando eu tento dar um $_POST['uf'] ou em qualquer outro input que não seja cep num arquivo PHP, o campo aparece em branco para mim.

Vocês teriam alguma ideia para me ajudar?

Agradecido

Answer (score 1):

O erro é devido ao método definido na tag .

Está como GET

```
<form method="get" action=".">
```

Troque para POST

```
<form method="post" action=".">
```

Comment: Já havia percebido tal fato e havia trocado para post, mas na hora da minha action, em que chamo o PHP, não consigo capturar o valor. Só consigo capturar os valores digitados. Agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema, como o preenchimento não estava chegando ao php fiz uma requisição com o curl dentro da minha página php ao endereço viacep.com.br/ws/"cep da requisição post aqui"/piped/ e consegui preencher o restante dos campos que estavam sem dados.